# rename dynamic strings using notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to rename different asp labels IDs at a time.

Like,

```
<asp:Label ID="home" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="11px" />

<asp:Label ID = "aboutUs" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="11px" />

<asp:Label ID="contact" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="11px" />


<asp:Label ID= "gallery" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="11px" />
```

I've to concatenate "**_lbl**" in the end of every label ID. Like, **home_lbl**, **aboutUs_lbl**. How can I do it using notepad++ search and replace feature?

Also check for the prevailing spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ID\s*=\s*"([^"]+)(?<!_lbl)" # find
ID="\1_lbl" # replace
```

`(?<!_lbl)` prevents extra `_lbl`s.

Make sure you select `Regular expressions` in the search options.